# How to Update Wordpress Page Excerpts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I wanted to update all my pages' excerpt with custom excerpt. So I created my own plugin with few lines of code. I dunno why it is not working, This is my code

```
function update_my_metadata_new(){
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    // Run a loop and update every meta data
    if(in_category('books')){
        $the_post = array(
        'ID'           => $page->ID,//the ID of the Post
        'post_excerpt' => 'Read books',);
        wp_update_post( $the_post );
    }
  }
}
```

This plugin will loop into all pages in the given category and update the excerpts, when activated.
and I have enabled excerpts for pages by adding this code.

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

to the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Where do you run `update_my_metadata_new`? Are you running it on a action hook?

Comment: I created a custom plugin, and entered this code, so when the plugin is activated it kinda runs on all pages.

Comment: That function never runs unless you actually call it. How are you calling that function?

Comment: I was looking at your function more, and there are a bunch of things that are possibly wrong: 1. `Pages` don't have taxonomies (e.g. categories), unless you added them through something custom. `Posts` do. 2. There is no reason to run this on every single page load. That is excessive. 3. You should run this once if you want to update all current posts, and then hook into [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) for all new posts.

Comment: I have enabled tags and categories through a plugin, and Yes, you are right, I should run this only once., But its not even running once

Comment: If that's the case, since you are using `in_category` outside of the loop, you also need to pass the post id - `if( in_category( 'books', $page->ID ) )`. Also, you still haven't answered how you are calling this function.

Comment: Ok I didn't quite understand what you were asking, as I am new to coding I am using `register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'update_my_metadata_new');` to call this function. And your suggestion worked for me, If you enter it as an answer. I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `in_category` outside of the main loop. You need to pass in the ID of the page for `in_category` to work:

`in_category('books', $page->ID )`

```
function update_my_metadata_new(){
    $pages = get_pages();
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        /* pass the page ID here */
        if( in_category( 'books', $page->ID ) ){
            $the_post = array(
                'ID'           => $page->ID,//the ID of the Post
                'post_excerpt' => 'Read books',
            );
            wp_update_post( $the_post );
    }
  }
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'update_my_metadata_new');
```